# Не отрабатывает скрипт с сервера

Tags: php, сервер

Здравствуйте, запускаю скрипт из консоли сервера `php -f path/constructor.php &`
Вот скрипт:

```
$fp = fopen(dirname(__FILE__)."/object.json", "w");
fwrite($fp, json_encode($res));
fclose($fp);
```

Но $res не записывается хотя просто текст в файл записывается, помогите.

Comment: Где лежит файл object.json, который надо переписать? И какие у него права?

Comment: файл небось рядом со скрипом, а при запуске из консоли текущая рабочая директория - та из которой запускаете.

Comment: да вы правы файл рядом, как задавать права?

Comment: `fopen(dirname(__FILE__)."/object.json", "w")`; попробуйте